# How do I know which version of OpenGL I am using?

Tags: opengl

I started writing programs, in C (for now) using GLFW and OpenGL. The question I have is that, how do I know which version of OpenGL my program will use? My laptop says that my video card has OpenGL 3.3. Typing "glxinfo | grep -i opengl" returns:

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 9600M GT/PCI/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 285.05.09
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL extensions:
```

So is OpenGL 3.3 automatically being used ?

Comment: So have you figured out the solution yourself and forgot about your question or do you still have some unclarities? In the former case just abandoning a question is extremely bad practice and in the latter case feel free to ask any further questions about existing answers or even post your own answer if different from the already existing ones.

Comment: If you want to check *GLEW* version on *Linux* from terminal, you can install `glew-utils` and run `visualinfo | grep "OpenGL version"`.

Answer (score 21):

Just call `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` (once the context is initialized, of course) and put out the result (which is actually the same that glxinfo does, I suppose):

```
printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
```

Your program should automatically use the highest possible version your hardware and driver support, which in your case seems to be 3.3. But for creating a core-profile context for OpenGL 3+ (one where deprecated functionality has been completely removed) you have to take special measures. But since version 2.7 GLFW has means for doing this, using the `glfwOpenWindowHint` function. But if you don't want to explicitly disallow deprecated functionality, you can just use the context given to you by the default context creation functions of GLFW, which will as said support the highest possible version for your hardware and drivers.

But also keep in mind that for using OpenGL functionality higher than version 1.1 you need to retrieve the corresponding function pointers or use a library that handles this for you, like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: "But if I remember correctly you need a special function to create an OpenGL context for versions higher than 2.1." Not true. You don't need to use WGL/GLX_ARB_create_context_attribs to get higher than GL 2.1. The regular context creation API will give you a context that is backwards-compatible with 2.1. So if 3.3 compatibility is supported, that's what you'll get.

Comment: @NicolBolas Ok, updated the answer. I don't have practical 3+ experience yet, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Christian - also specifically a windows limitation. MSFT only ship a opengl 1.1 implementation so even if your graphics card driver supports something newer you need to use GLEW or manually load the dlls and call the functions by addresses

Comment: @MartinBeckett: It's not just a Windows limitation. Most Linux OpenGL headers don't include anything more than about OpenGL 1.2 or so. You have to use glXGetProcAddress to get the function pointers for anything else. Also, you don't have to _manually_ load DLLs on Windows at all; that's what wglGetProcAddress is for.