# How can I check my OpenGL version?

Tags: opengl, compatibility

when I run `glxinfo` I get:

```
...
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
...
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
...
GLX version: 1.4
...
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 9500M GS/PCI/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 3.2.0 NVIDIA 195.36.24
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.50 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
...
```

Without polling extension functionality, from what version's functions may I assume supported? Minimum of 1.4 and 3.2 seems incredibly historic, so I assume glx version is not numbered in parallel with OpenGL version...

What GLSL version may I assume? It displays the Cg compiler version, but what's my GLSL version?

Comment: See this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909358/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-opengl-i-am-using?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

GLX is the protocol that transports OpenGL commands in a X11 command stream. The most recent version of GLX is 1.4.

The OpenGL version is told in the "OpenGL version string". And you got 3.2

> so I assume glx version is not numbered in parallel with OpenGL version...

No it's not, because they're two different things. GLX transports OpenGL, it doesn't implement it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, basically it turns out that it is just what it says:

GLX version 1.4

OpenGL version 3.2

GLSL version 1.50 **via** NVIDIA Cg Compiler